# Virtual method with default parameter changed behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I was asked to make a slight change on an old project build with Visual Studio 2013 VC++. So, I installed VS2013, made the change, compiled it but its behavior has changed on a code that I didn't touch.

After the update, a virtual method that was calling the method on the derived class is calling the method on the base class now.

I'm not a C++ expert but I can see that this a bad practice. All I want to know if there was a breaking change in C++ around this so I can explain to the person who asked me to update this project.

```cpp
class BaseItem
{
  public:
    virtual void SetValue(int first, int* second = nullptr)
    {
    };
}

class DerivedItem : public BaseItem
{
  public:
    virtual void SetValue(int first)
    {
    };
}
```

```cpp
BaseItem* item = new DerivedItem();
// Before: SetValue on the DerivedItem was called.
// After: SetValue on the BaseItem is called.
item->SetValue(5, nullptr);
```

and if I edit the **DerivedItem** like this:

```cpp
class DerivedItem : public BaseItem
{
  public:
    virtual void SetValue(int first, int* second = nullptr)
    {
    };
}
```

the `SetValue` on the **DerivedItem** is called again.

Comment: If the functions do not have the same signature, they are _different_ functions. Read about function overloading in C++. If you want to really see what's going on, declare `DerivedItem::SetValue` with the `override` specifier, and only one of your examples will compile.

Comment: The `DerivedItem::SetValue(int first)` is a different function than the `BaseItem::SetValue()` because they have different parameter lists.   To overload functions, they must have the same signature, i.e. quantity of parameters and return type.  A default parameter counts as a parameter (the compiler sets the value if the parameter is not specified).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. `int second = nullptr`, missing semicolons are the signs of a not real simplified code.

Comment: `SetValue` in `DerivedItem` does not override `SetValue` in `BaseItem`. Never did. What the question describes would be a compiler bug.

Comment: I suggest you add the `override` modifier to the derived function, like [shown here](https://godbolt.org/z/18ccsxsWf) (note that I had to fix some of your other errors). Then you will get an error that your function doesn't actually override the base class function. For the function to override the base class function, it needs to have the *exact* same arguments. What you're doing is creating a brand new and distinct function, which will *hide* the base class function.

Comment: `nullptr` is not a valid initializer for an `int`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, guys. I corrected the code mistakes. I can't reproduce the old version behavior, but I just know from the logs that the derived class SetValue was called.

Comment: **I can't reproduce the old version behavior.** So, the question is unanswerable. And still missing semicolons there.

Comment: @PeteBecker the behaviour described in the question is correct, although not presented clearly. Their description starting "After: " refers to the code at the start of the question, and "Before:" refers to code not posted, but which didn't have the second parameter at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function overriding is based on the parameters and their types, not taking default values into account.  After the change, `DerivedItem::SetValue` is no longer an override of `BaseItem::SetValue`, it is just a member function that shadows the base function of same name.

You can have the compiler diagnose this for you by using the `override` keyword whenever you intend overriding to happen:

```
class DerivedItem : public BaseItem
{
    virtual void SetValue(int first) override
```

then it will give an error if the function is not actually overriding a function from the base class (as opposed to a silent change in runtime behaviour).

---

To override a function you will have to make the derived class signature match the base class, as you have found.

In my opinion -- it's cleaner and more robust to avoid default parameters entirely , and add another overload of the function to support a different parameter set. So instead, the base class would have:

```
virtual void SetValue(int first){ ... }
virtual void SetValue(int first, int second){ ... }
```

and the derived could override either one or both. This approach also plays nicer with existing code that calls SetValue.

Comment: Since it seems that there were not any breaking changes around this, I might have a different version of the project. I'll follow your tips and fix the code, so the app behaves the way it's supposed to. Thanks!